# Unable to install OpenSSL package with RVM on Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, openssl, rvm, osx-mountain-lion

I'm setting up RVM, Rails, etc., on a clean install of Mountain Lion.
I am following the guide "[How to Install Xcode, Homebrew, Git, RVM, & Ruby 1.9.3 on Snow Leopard, Lion, and Mountain Lion](http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/)".

After installing RVM with Ruby (1.9.3) I do a `rvm requirement` and it appears I should install apple-gcc42 using Homebrew:

```
Homebrew:

  If you are using Homebrew, you can install the apple-gcc42 and required libraries from homebrew/dupes:

      brew update
      brew tap homebrew/dupes
      brew install autoconf automake apple-gcc42
      rvm pkg install openssl
```

When I get to the OpenSSL package install I get the following error and don't know how to proceed:

```
marvin:~ george$ rvm --skip-autoreconf pkg install openssl
Fetching openssl-1.0.1c.tar.gz to /Users/george/.rvm/archives
######################################################################## 100.0%
Downloaded archive checksum did not match, archive was removed!
If you wish to continue with not matching download add '--verify-downloads 2' after the command.


Please note that it's required to reinstall all rubies:

    rvm reinstall all --force

Updating openssl certificates
Error running 'update_openssl_certs', please read /Users/george/.rvm/log/openssl.certs.log
```

The contents of the specified log file are as below, presumably because the OpenSSL archive has been discarded:

```
[2012-12-26 22:23:04] update_openssl_certs
/Users/george/.rvm/scripts/functions/support: line 139: cd: /Users/george/.rvm/usr/ssl: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I have run the command with the --verify-downloads 2 option and things seem to be working. I dont really understand why that is necessary though...

Comment: the downloaded archive is not the same that was originally uploaded and that is matched against the checksum test. Usually this is no big deal but since openssl is about encryption you should still be careful. In most cases this problem is due to updated packages.

Comment: make sure to open an ticket for RVM -> https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues

Comment: Have a look [at this other stackoverflow question which answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213268/rvm-pkg-install-openssl) what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I used hombrew to install opensll.

```
brew install openssl
```

If that doesn't work check this link for answers.

http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html