# rvm pkg install openssl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gcc, rvm

I tried to install openssl but when it says:

> it's required to reinstall all rubies:
>
> ```
> rvm reinstall all --force
> ```

```
rvm reinstall ruby-2.0.0-p0 --with-gcc=gcc-4.7 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

After I run the above line I get You requested building with 'gcc-4.7' but it is not in your path. I have xcode already installed which I thought has gcc already installed.

Anyone know any answers to this.

Comment: Why are you specifying `gcc-4.7` instead of `gcc` located at `/usr/bin/gcc`? If you run `which gcc-4.7` do you see any binary in the response?

Comment: I'm running gcc-4.7 because that's what it suggested for me to do. When I type which gcc-4.7 I get nothing. When I run which gcc I get /usr/bin/gcc

Answer (score 0):

As you said in the comments, you ran `which gcc-4.7` and it returned nothing. This confirms what RVM is telling you, `gcc-4.7` isn't on your `$PATH`. If you know you have `gcc-4.7` as a binary existing on your computer somewhere, add it's directory path to `$PATH`

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/the/binrary
```

Otherwise, since you've said `which gcc` does return `/usr/bin/gcc` you can either

- Omit the `--with-gcc` option when running `rvm reinstall ...`
- Specify the `gcc` binary you **do** have on your `$PATH` with `--with-gcc=gcc` or `--with-gcc=/usr/bin/gcc`